# Catalan Number Modulo Prime

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, catalan-numbers

What is the fastest method to find the $n$th Catalan number modulo some prime $p$? I was looking at Lucas's method to solve $\binom{2n}{n}$ fast, but not sure if it will work. What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Well $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$, so the Lucas method sounds like a good idea.